# SSIS package using excel source failing on IIS server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, excel, iis, ssis

I have a simple SSIS package which has an excel source dumping data in SQL table.
It works fine in BIDS when run manually.
It also works when called from an ASP.NET application on my local.

When the same ASP.NET application was deployed on IIS server it is giving me the following error:

```
The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "10.xxx.xx.xxx.<DB>.<User>" failed with error code 0xC0202009
```

Note:
Run64bitRunTime is set to false as suggested in many posts for similar issue.

What could be the issue?

Error Log from SQL Job running the package:

```
SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDB_NOPROVIDER_ERROR.  The requested OLE DB provider Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 is not registered. Error code: 0x00000000.  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Service Components"  Hresult: 0x80040154  Description: "Class not registered".  End Error  Error: 2015-06-02 14:26:22.79     Code: 0xC020801C     Source: Data Flow Task Excel Source [1]     Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "Excel Connection Manager" failed with error code 0xC0209302.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.  End Error  Error: 2015-06-02 14:26:22.79     Code: 0xC0047017     Source: Data Flow Task SSIS.Pipeline     Description: component "Excel Source" (1) failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801C.  End Error  Error: 2015-06-02 14:26:22.79     Code: 0xC004700C     Source: Data Flow Task SSIS.Pipeline     Description: One or more component failed validation.  End Error  Error: 2015-06-02 14:26:22.79     Code: 0xC0024107     Source: Data Flow Task      Description: There were errors during task validation.  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  2:26:21 PM  Finished: 2:26:22 PM  Elapsed:  1.031 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.,00:00:01,0,0,,,,0
```

Comment: could be connectivity or permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Typically when a package runs in BIDS and in the integration services, but fails as a job or when called from an external application, it is a permissions issue associated with the SSIS proxy.  The default logon being applied in the ASP.NET application should also be set up in a credential and that credential should then be applied in a Proxy with permission to apply the SSIS subsystem.

Apply the steps outlined in the following link:

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2163/running-a-ssis-package-from-sql-server-agent-using-a-proxy-account/

Comment: But I am not getting admin / access issue. I have edited my question to included error log.It's about Excel COnnection manager issue.I am using xml config with stored credentials and also I have enable Use 32-bit runtime which has been suggested in most places over the internet.Please suggest.

Comment: It sounds like a component or permission required for the connection is missing from the IIS server that currently exists on the database server.  Is Excel installed on the IIS server?  I suspect that it is installed on the database server where you successfully ran BIDS and the ASP.NET code?